# toram loads entire pendrive to RAM

Tags: boot, grub2, usb

I am new to ask Ubuntu so bear with me :)

I have made a multiboot usb that I created using AIO BOOT creator. I have multiple debian distros ubuntu, lubuntu, kali... on it and they all boot fine. I am specifically asking about Ubuntu fyi. I am trying to load the os of choice into ram on boot. I am testing this on a system with 12GB of RAM. What ends up happening is it tries to load the entire flash drive to ram not just the filesystem.squashfs. I know this because the warning message 'not nough free memory (11987280k < 21707767k) to copy live media to RAM' changed with the used space of the flash drive. Even when I used 'toram=filesystem.squashfs' it did the same. But kali linux works with 'toram=filesystem.squashfs'.

Ubuntu uses BOOT=casper. Kali uses BOOT=live which I believe explains this.

My question is how do I avoid loading the entire flashdrive contents into ram and just filesystem.squashfs. Or/And how do I specify 'toram=filesystem.squashfs' when BOOT=casper

He is the config file entry

```
menuentry "Try Ubuntu without installing - toRAM" 
{ set gfxpayload=keep 
    linux ${extract_path}/casper/vmlinuz file=${extract_path}/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper live-media-path=${extract_path}/casper/ cdrom-detect/try-usb=true noprompt floppy.allowed_drive_mask=0 ignore_uuid toram --- 
    initrd ${extract_path}/casper/initrd.lz 
}
```

[image]